# Hotels and food-service during shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, employment

Could someone point me to the right direction ([halacha](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/597)) regarding the validity of being served by a Jew working at the hotel where I reside during shabbat?

Basically I'm making him "work" on shabbat when I ask to clean the table or to refill an empty bowl... I know people explains this by comparing with being invited at someone's house shabbat but still I would like to understand it more.

Furthermore, I know for sure it's "allowed" since they have a "kosher lamehadrin" certificate on the door but still it disturbs me and I would like to  take a look at the halachot on this subject.

EDIT:
[Here](http://www.rabanut.gov.il/vf%5Cib_items%5C5%5Cnohal_malon.pdf) is a link (Hebrew) to the Rabanut HaRashit in Israel concerning the kashrut in hotel (pages 7/8/9 for Shabbat)

Answer (score 5):

There is a concept in halacha called "havla'ah"; lit. swallowing up. Although it is forbidden to pay someone for work they did for you on Shabbos, if you are paying a weekly rate and Shabbos happens to be one of the seven days, it's permitted. In the hotel case, the Jewish waiters must work a little before or after Shabbos and be paid for the entire job together.

Source: Shulchan Aruch OC 306:4.

Comment: Thank you for the source, but what if he shows up only on shabbat ? How could I know, haRabanut in Israel doesn't control when a worker will check-in to work and yet they obtain a kosher lamehadrin certificate.

Comment: Is the hechsher certifying that the food is kosher, or that everything related to the function was done in accordance with halacha? If the latter, the rav hamachshir must ensure that.

Comment: [rabanut.gov.il](http://www.rabanut.gov.il/vf%5Cib_items%5C5%5Cnohal_malon.pdf) this link points to a pdf concerning what should be controlled in hotels in order to be ready for shabbat. page 7/8 concern shabbat directly the rest are general rules regarding kosher food. There is nothing regarding workers check-in/check-out

Comment: Isn't the correct transliteration 'havla'ah'?