# Does caring for children in foster care count as work?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, money, children-parenting, employment

If someone looked after foster children on weekends (from Friday afternoon until Sunday afternoon) and received remuneration does this count as work and not permissible on the Sabbath?

Comment: Do you look after them *only* on the Sabbath, or also on other days *including* the Sabbath? This makes a big difference.

Comment: If it's including the Sabbath, then see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19050/hotels-and-food-service-during-shabbat/19053 for a similar situation. If you mean only on the Sabbath then looking after them is not a problem, but getting paid is.

Comment: It is from Friday afternoon until Sunday afternoon. Thanks

Comment: Ideally you should ask your Rabbi for practical matters like this, but the answer in the link above applies to you as well. So I guess this could be marked as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodea, harry!  Thanks for your question.  I look forward to hearing more from you.  Just keep in mind that this is not a place to look for actual halakhic advice (you should [see your rabbi for that](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi)).  Treat this place as a room full of strangers who can point to some sources (but not all relevant sources).

Answer (score 2):

[As Ariel stated](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19050/hotels-and-food-service-during-shabbat/19053), in theory one can perform services (not physically-creative actions like plowing, planting, cooking, writing, burning and the like) such as childcare, waiting/bussing tables, teaching/sermonizing/performing prayer services if there is a lump payment for a period of time that includes some non-Shabbat.

Thus you could pay a babysitter for "the period 6-8PM", where 6-7PM is shabbat and 7-8PM isn't; or a rabbi for "answering questions during the week and delivering a sermon on shabbat."

In theory I don't see why foster care should be different, but as always ask your rabbi.